# References to a label

Tags: hyperref, nameref

I would like to create a label and display in the pdf-output, where the label is used:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{nameref, hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{The first chapter}
\label{ch:ch1}
This chapter is referenced in the following chapters: The second chapter, The third chapter\\
The list should be updated automatically.

\chapter{The second chapter}
Read this chapter first: \nameref{ch:ch1}

\chapter{The third chapter}
Read this chapter first: \nameref{ch:ch1}

\end{document}
```

In the code I have written the list by hand, but I would like to create it dynamically on build. How do I do this?

[image: Output snippet]

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) what exactly is your question?

Comment: Is the question how to create an index for the references of the given label?

Comment: nameref is loaded by hyperref already. And what is the question?  Did you compile twice?

Comment: As I understand the question, the list `The second chapter, The third chapter` should be created automatically

Comment: Yes, samcarter is correct.

Comment: to add to @samcarter's comment, what you want to be generated automatically is the list in chapter 1.  sorry, i don't know any way of doing that.  ordinarily, an author would place a label in each of the referenced chapters, and a reference in chapter 1 to these labels.

Comment: In this particular situation I have defined an algorithm, which is referenced to from several places. I would like the beginnng of the algorithm to automatically know who is referencing to it. It would help the reader to realize the consequences of changing the algorithm.